# social sprite images same line with follow us text in front

Tags: css

Anyway to make Follow Us text inline with sprite images?

http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/66/

```
<ul class="social_Emp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Follow us:
  <li class="Emp_twitter"><a href="{if $userInfo.TwitterPage} {$userInfo.TwitterPage}{else}#{/if}" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
  <li class="Emp_facebook"><a href="{if $userInfo.FBPage}{$userInfo.FBPage}{else}#{/if}" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
  <li class="Emp_google"><a href="{if $userInfo.GooglePage}{$userInfo.GooglePage}{else}#{/if}" alt="Google"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the *Follow us:* text is not part of the list, it would be semantically more correct to bring it outside of the `ul` block. Then, just add `display: inline-block;` to the `.social_Emp` class to make the `ul` act just like text:

http://jsfiddle.net/qeYQ4/

In order to align the text with the icons, you may also want to wrap the text in a span with `position: relative` and `top: 5px` (or whatever pixel value you like):

http://jsfiddle.net/qeYQ4/1/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="social_Emp"><li>Follow us:</li>
              <li class="Emp_twitter"><a href="{if $userInfo.TwitterPage}{$userInfo.TwitterPage}{else}#{/if}" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
              <li class="Emp_facebook"><a href="{if $userInfo.FBPage}{$userInfo.FBPage}{else}#{/if}" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
              <li class="Emp_google"><a href="{if $userInfo.GooglePage}{$userInfo.GooglePage}{else}#{/if}" alt="Google"></a></li>
            </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.social_Emp {position: relative;margin: 10px auto;}
.social_Emp li {background: url(http://www.bestjob.my/mod/CSS/sprites/Sprite_vertical.png) no-repeat;
position: absolute;display: block;list-style: none;}
.social_Emp a {height:24px;display: block;}
.social_Emp .Emp_twitter {left:76px;background-position: 0 -600px;width:24px;height:24px;}
.social_Emp .Emp_facebook {left:106px;background-position: 0 -645px;width:24px;height:24px;}
.social_Emp .Emp_google {left:136px;background-position: 0 -844px;width:24px;height:24px;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/67/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.social_Emp {position: relative;margin: 10px}
.social_Emp li {background: url(http://www.bestjob.my/mod/CSS/sprites/Sprite_vertical.png) no-repeat;
}
.social_Emp a {height:24px;display: block;}
.social_Emp .Emp_twitter {left:20px;background-position: 0 -600px;width:24px;height:24px;float:left}
.social_Emp .Emp_facebook {left:50px;background-position: 0 -645px;width:24px;height:24px;float:left}
.social_Emp .Emp_google {left:80px;background-position: 0 -844px;width:24px;height:24px;float:left}
```

Please try this

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute position for the li positioning. You can't get anything inline with absolute positioning. By default, it takes an element out of the regular document flow.

Here is a JS Fiddle with the fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/68/

Changes made:

```
.social_Emp li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}
```